# How to write text on the same line inside TabBar Icon?

Tags: css, react-native

I have an issue with the text of the `TabBar` that is not written on same line like shown in the [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7wmZ.png). On small screen (Iphone 12) it works perfectly but when i changed to big screen of  (Ipad 12.9 inch) How can i prevent that?

I have my code:

```js
<Tab.Screen
          name="Shop"
          component={ShopNavigator}
          options={(navigation, route) => ({
            title: 'Shop',
            tabBarVisible: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ props, focused }) => (
              <View {...props} >
              <View style={{flex: 2, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Image source={SHOP} resizeMode="contain" style={[styles.imgSize, focused && { opacity:1 }]} />
                <Text style={[styles.label, focused && { opacity:1, textDecorationLine: 'underline' }]}>Vente en ligne</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            )
          })}
/>
```

```css
imgSize: {
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    padding: 15,
    opacity: 0.8,
  },
  label: {
    color: '#FFF',
    fontSize: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Barlow-Bold',
    opacity: 0.8,
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give it more space:

```
label: {
color: '#FFF',
fontSize: 10,
textAlign: 'center',
fontFamily: 'Barlow-Bold',
opacity: 0.8,
width: "100%" //should take. 100% of the available space
}
```

I would also add the `numberOfLines = 1` prop to the `Text` component to prevent incredibly small screens

Answer (score 0):

Nothing works except returning empty function for renderLabel then having renderIcon display icon and text (placed side by side)

here is the code for more understanding

```
const renderTabBar = props => {

    return <TabBar
      {...props}
      indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}
      style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}

renderIcon={({ route, focused, color }) => {

        return <Text style={{ color: '#000', margin: 8 }}><AntIcon
          size={13}
          name={route?.icon}
          color={'#000'}
        /> 
          {" "} {route.title}
        </Text>}
      }

      renderLabel={({ route, focused, color }) => {}}
/>
}
```